# Phase-symmetric normal matrix

Tags: matrices

I define a complex matrix A as phase-symmetric if for every pair of elements elements $a_{ij}$ and $a_{ji}$,

$$a_{ij} = r_1\angle{\theta}$$

$$a_{ji} = r_2\angle{\theta}$$

where $r1,r2$ are real and $-\frac{\pi}{2}\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{2}$. ie: both elements have the same complex phase.

I want to prove that a complex normal matrix is phase-symmetric if and only if it is symmetric.

Any hints would be great. This is not a homework or textbook question. Just from my own personal investigations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, $$\pmatrix{0 &  e^{i\theta}\cr - e^{i\theta} & 0\cr}$$ is normal and complex phase-symmetric, according to your definition, but not symmetric.

Comment: sorry, you're right. never mind.